# ¿Map con un solo elemento es desperdicio de recursos?

Tags: java, optimización

Tengo un map con otro map adentro como el siguiente :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Double>>
```

sin embargo el segundo map siempre tendrá solo un elemento, por lo cual me parece que estoy desperdiciando memoria por que a fin de cuenta un map es una lista y prácticamente es una lista que siempre tendrá un elemento, aunque también pienso que si solo tiene un elemento solo ocupa la memoria necesaria para ese solo elemento, la pregunta es la siguiente ¿Estoy desperdiciando memoria? ¿Existe alguna manera más optima para realizar lo que quiero? todo seria más fácil si hubiera un map con dos valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por tu descripción, me suena que lo que en realidad quieres es que el valor de tu map contenga 2 valores. En efecto, el que uses un `Map` para esto parece un abuso de su función y también es cierto que habrá un cierto grado de desperdicio.

La forma correcta de hacer esto es definiendo una clase para ese propósito en vez de usar otro map.

Ejemplo (ajusta los nombres según tu necesidad):

```
public class MiTuple {
    private String miString;
    private Double miDouble;

    public MiTuple(String miString, Double miDouble) {
        this.miString = miString;
        this.miDouble = miDouble;
    }

    public String getMiString() {
        return this.miString;
    }

    public Double getMiDouble() {
        return this.miDouble;
    }
}
```

De esta forma, puedes definir tu map de una forma mas usual sin "desperdicios", pero con todos los datos que necesitas:

```
Map<Integer, MiTuple>
```

... o, como bien comenta @Awes0meM4n, y como puedes encontrar en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671052/4955425), puedes crear una clase equivalente usando genéricos para representar 2 valores de cualquier tipo. Esto te permitiría recuperar la misma clase para diferentes situaciones:

> ```
> public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
>   public final X x; 
>   public final Y y; 
>   public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
>     this.x = x; 
>     this.y = y; 
>   } 
> }
> ```

En este caso, definirías tu map de la siguiente manera:

```
Map<Integer, Tuple<String, Double>>
```

Comment: Podrías cambiar el código añadiendo genéricos y así le valdría para otros casos.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n: Muy cierto lo que dices.